# SQL ORACLE:Table restructuring

Tags: oracle

I  am looking to merge data in way described below:

I have a table below:

table: PTLANALYSIS

```
RENTALDATE
OUTBOUND,
INBOUND,
VEHICLE_SIZE,
COMPETITOR,
RATE;
```

The data I am trying to load into the tabs:

```
RENTALDATE,
OUTBOUND,
INBOUND,
VEHICLE_SIZE,
LOLY,
KAY,
RATE;
```

Now LOLY and KAY are suppose to be in column "Competitor" in table PTLANALYSIS. Can someone help me merge my data in an appropriate manner, the output should look something like this...

```
Rental Date | OUTBOUND | INBOUND | VEHICLE_SIZE | COMPETITOR | RATE
12/28/2019    223          333        small         loly        33.5
12/28/2019    223          333        small         kay         33.5
```

Currently it looks like this in my csv..

```
Rental Date  | OUTBOUND | INBOUND | VEHICLE_SIZE | lolyRATE   | KAYRATE 
12/28/2019       223         333          small      33.5          NULL     
12/28/2019       223         333          small      NULL          33.5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the relation between `OUTBOUND` values in the sample data and in the resultset ? Same question for `INBOUND`.

Comment: How to get that data from csv? For e.g with `loly`, why `2019-02-07` become `12/28/2019`, `11` become `223` and so on? And what about value `179.1` AND `21.3`, as your output, you will lost them?

Comment: there is no relation between the data, sorry if I was confusing. They are 4 different records all together. I just wanted to show the relation between competitor and loly/kay.... date is not a concern either. I just need a query to have the data structured like the output in the format in table ATLANALYSIS.

Comment: I need to make column " Competitor" only list "loly" or "KAY" and the new column  "Rate" list the corresponding rate value. I have edited the data above to match the same records to display it better. I will be loading the data into a table that match the CSV columns then I'll change it with the script? I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: The sample contents of the CSV file you posted don't match the structure of the file you posted earlier. So which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the columns in the CSV file have fixed targets. You need to evaluate the LOLYRATE and KAYRATE to conditionally populate COMPETITOR and RATE. Something like this:

```
insert into PTLANALYSIS (
    RENTALDATE
    OUTBOUND,
    INBOUND,
    VEHICLE_SIZE,
    COMPETITOR,
    RATE
)
select 
    RENTALDATE,
    OUTBOUND,
    INBOUND,
    VEHICLE_SIZE,
    case when LOLYRATE is not null then 'loly' else 'kay' end as competitor,
    coalesce(LOLYRATE, KAYRATE) as rate
from ext_table
;
```

You haven't said how you intend to load the data but I have assumed an external table, because it allows you to use SQL, and everything is easier with SQL. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E.htm#SUTIL011).